# ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6 in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode10

I am receiving an error while trying to run the app using pod installation of “IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation” on iOS using Xcode 10

```
ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

Should remove libstdc++ from other linker flags in your xcode project

Follow

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/23/mfp-support-for-ios12/#known-issues